# Can't close ticket channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, ticket-system

I'm using discord.ext.slash to create a close slash command for my ticket bot and this won't close the channel which I think it should. Thanks!

```
@client.slash_cmd()
async def close(ctx: slash.Context):
    """Closes the ticket"""
    await ctx.delete()
```

Edit:
When running this command, I get

```
  File "/home/runner/Ticket-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/slash/__init__.py", line 1371, in on_interaction_create
    raise commands.CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10015): Unknown Webhook
```

And then when I try to use ctx.channel.delete() instead of ctx.delete(), I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Ticket-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/slash/__init__.py", line 1371, in on_interaction_create
    raise commands.CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work"? Any errors coming out of it? Does your bot have the permissions to delete channels? Can your bot see the channel? Because ``ctx.delete`` won't delete a channel for you, and ``ctx.channel.delete`` should.

Comment: As mentioned, you need to delete the channel of the context. You may also find it useful to add a check to make sure that it's the ticket channel being deleted, not some other chnanel you wouldn't want to delete.

Comment: @stijndcl Yes the bot has permissions to delete channels and see it. I edited and put the errors in my original message so you can see.

Comment: @stijndcl I think the reason why `ctx.channel.delete` isn't working because I'm declaring ctx as `ctx: slash.Context`

Comment: @KarterSanamo the type annotation doesn't matter at all, its only purpose is for your IDE to give suggestions. Slash.Context is even the correct one so I don't see why that would be the issue.

Comment: @stijndcl well when I would make a normal command ( not using slash )using `@client.command` etc, and just passing ctx but not declaring it as `ctx: Slash.Context` the command would work perfectly fine. Which is why I thought that was the issue. Just curious if there was any work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I Just made the bot send a message in the channel and then used `on_message` to watch for that message and then close the channel. I know it's not a professional way to do this but it works so.

Comment: could you add some code showing how you did this?